# How do i get MvxTrace to emit messages when using MvxIoCSupportingTest

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

Inside

```
public class PathTests : MvxIoCSupportingTest
```

I have

```
    [Test]
    public void GetTemp()
    {
        var temp = Path.GetTempPath();
        MvxTrace.Trace("hello from Mvx");
        Trace.WriteLine("hello from Trace");
        Debug.WriteLine("hello from Debug");
        Assert.NotNull(temp);
    }
```

However, nothing shows up in the test output for Mvx. The output is

> hello from Trace hello from Debug

(In the example above, Trace is from System.Diagnostics.) In http://blog.fire-development.com/2013/06/29/mvvmcross-enable-unit-testing/ it looks like

```
_ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTrace>(new TestTrace());
```

what am I missing?

**Update.** I am using NCrunch, here is the entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Loqu8.MvvmCross.Plugins.IO;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Test.Core;
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Platform;
using Cirrious.CrossCore;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace IO.Wpf.Tests
{

    [TestFixture]
    public class PathTests : MvxIoCSupportingTest
    {    
        public PathTests()
        {
            Setup();
            Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxPath>(new MvxPath());
            Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IFileSystem>(new DesktopFileSystem());
            Ioc.RegisterType<IFile, FileSystemFile>();
            Ioc.RegisterType<IFolder, FileSystemFolder>();
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetTemp()
        {
            var temp = Path.GetTempPath();
            MvxTrace.Trace("hello from Mvx");
            Trace.WriteLine("hello from Trace");
            Debug.WriteLine("hello from Debug");
            Assert.NotNull(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I add your tests to http://blog.fire-development.com/2013/06/29/mvvmcross-enable-unit-testing/ then I see output:

```
mvx: Diagnostic:   0.01 hello from Mvx
hello from Trace
hello from Debug
```

Complete test code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MvvmCrossTestSetup
{
    private IMvxIoCProvider _ioc;

    protected IMvxIoCProvider Ioc
    {
        get { return _ioc; }
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        ClearAll();
    }

    protected void ClearAll()
    {
        // fake set up of the IoC
        MvxSingleton.ClearAllSingletons();
        _ioc = MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialise();
        _ioc.RegisterSingleton(_ioc);
        _ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTrace>(new TestTrace());
        RegisterAdditionalSingletons();
        InitialiseSingletonCache();
        InitialiseMvxSettings();
        MvxTrace.Initialize();
    }

    protected void InitialiseMvxSettings()
    {
        _ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxSettings>(new MvxSettings());
    }

    protected virtual void RegisterAdditionalSingletons()
    {
    }

    private static void InitialiseSingletonCache()
    {
        MvxSingletonCache.Initialise();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetTemp()
    {
        Setup();

        var temp = Path.GetTempPath();
        MvxTrace.Trace("hello from Mvx");
        Trace.WriteLine("hello from Trace");
        Debug.WriteLine("hello from Debug");
        Assert.NotNull(temp);
    }

    private class TestTrace : IMvxTrace
    {
        public void Trace(MvxTraceLevel level, string tag, Func<string> message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(tag + ":" + level + ":" + message());
        }

        public void Trace(MvxTraceLevel level, string tag, string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(tag + ": " + level + ": " + message);
        }

        public void Trace(MvxTraceLevel level, string tag, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(tag + ": " + level + ": " + message, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Test run using Resharper Test Runner

> what am I missing?

No idea - I just followed the code from http://blog.fire-development.com/2013/06/29/mvvmcross-enable-unit-testing/ and combined it with the code you'd included. Maybe try comparing your code with the code from that blog? Or post your complete sample here so others can compare it?

Comment: Now you've posted your update, there is an obvious and easy to spot difference between the blog and your code - `MvxTrace.Initialize();`

Comment: But MvxTrace.Initailize is called in Setup in MvxIoCSupportingTest. If I try to call it again, I get Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException : MvxTrace already initialized

Comment: I'm missing _ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTrace>(new TestTrace()); i think